# How to merge data.tables of different column types in R?

Tags: r, merge, type-conversion, data.table

I have a data.table containing some data that I want to merge into another data.table. However, the type of the columns don't match.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
heading <- c("A","B","C")
temp <- data.table(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=3))
setnames(temp,names(temp),heading)

data <- data.table(A=2,B="hi")
merge(temp,data,by=c("A","B"))
```

The above gives me the error

```
Error in bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  : 
  x.'B' is a character column being joined to i.'B' which is type 'logical'.
Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

This is the case for any other data type mismatches.

In this case, I don't really care about what data type my `temp` data.table has originally, I want to match it to whatever type is in the `data` object. I also can't set the `NA`s to specific data types since I cannot determine that (or I'd rather not to keep it flexible) prior to the merge.

How can I make this work? Can I force a coercion?

Comment: Can you edit to include the line: `library(data.table)` it's just good manners.

Comment: You can convert the columns in `temp` to the correct classes in `data` prior merging I guess

Comment: use `rbindlist(list(temp,data), fill=T, use.names=T)`

Comment: `TRUE` vs `T` is equally good manners @N8TRO :-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr You're absolutely correct.  Edit: use `rbindlist(list(temp,data), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr though for the life of me, I can't understand why anyone would think it's ok to name something `T` or `F` other than `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively.  My rule of thumb is that all names must have at least 6 characters to try and force some explicit information about the variable in the name.

Comment: agreed. For the T vs F thing I just refer folks to: https://github.com/Ironholds/jammr

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up here using search engines, the answer to the question is:

```
rbindlist(list(temp,data), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
```

Full probs to @N8TRO (see the comments).